# Tensor rank explanation please.

Tags: tensors

What is the difference between (2,0) and (1,1) and (0,2) tensors?
The problem I was dealing with was a map $V \times V \to \Bbb R$ Would it be correct that a map V* x V would be (1,1) and a V* x V* would be a (2,0)?

The question is regarding a tutorial (youtube.com/watch?v=5oeWX3NUhMA) at where at 29:54 he says the tensor is a (0,2).

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Examples

Comment: Context in the fact that tensors are multilinear maps.What is wrong with the question.  The wiki reference did not help?  What do you want.

Comment: Context in the fact that tensors are multilinear maps.  What is wrong with the question?  The wiki reference did not help.

Comment: The problem I was dealing with was a map V x V ---> R  Would it be correct that a map V* x V would be (1,1) and a V* x V* would be a (2,0)  ??

Comment: Context here means what your thoughts are about the question, or where this problem arose for you - write out the problem you were working on, then say what your issue is. Edit this into the question, and then it can be re-opened.

Comment: The question is regarding a tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oeWX3NUhMA where at 29:54 he says the tensor is a (0,2).